# strange behavior in the order of execution of a function in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

The following method is binded to a send button that should send an email using Python's SMTP library. What I want is that a label in my screen displays a "sending..." Text before sending the mail then after sending the mail a popup will show a text that the mail was sent. The problem that I am facing is that after pressing the button nothing happens (the label text does not show) and after a moment( normal time for mail to be sent) the popup show and the text in the label shows... It is very strange to me that all output is displaying at the same time in stead of the normal order:

display text in label > send mail > show the popup after mail was sent.

My code is as follows:

```
def send_email(self):
    self.the_mail_feedback.text = "Sending..."#this is not showing at first but after execution!
    gmail_user = str(self.txt_from_mail.text)
    gmail_pwd = str(self.txt_password.text)
    FROM = str(self.txt_from_mail.text)
    TO = []
    TO.append(str(self.txt_to_mail.text))
    SUBJECT = "subject 1"
    TEXT = "some text..."

    message = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject:
    %s\n\n%s""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        self.pop.open()#a popup that says that the mail is sent...
        #self.the_mail_feedback.text="" #will uncomment when it works to reset feedback
    except:
        self.the_mail_feedback.text="Failed To Send Mail... Check Credentials
```

"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all these operations take place in the same thread, the main program loop. So for instance your second line *does* change the label text, but the ui doesn't update until your function finishes and releases control to the normal kivy eventloop. The eventloop then updates the graphical representation of the label.

So actually everything does take place in order, it's just the graphics aren't free to update until the function finishes, at which point everything happens at once. For the same reason, you'll find you can't do any touch input while the mail is sending.

To avoid this, you need to work with the eventloop and allow places for the normal kivy control flow to continue. Here's a quick example that I think should work:

```
def begin_send_email(self):
    self.the_mail_feedback.text = "Sending..."#this is not showing at first but after execution!
    Clock.schedule_once(self.finish_send_email, 0)

def finish_send_email(self, *args):
    gmail_user = str(self.txt_from_mail.text)
    gmail_pwd = str(self.txt_password.text)
    FROM = str(self.txt_from_mail.text)
    TO = []
    TO.append(str(self.txt_to_mail.text))
    SUBJECT = "subject 1"
    TEXT = "some text..."

    message = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject:
    %s\n\n%s""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        self.pop.open()#a popup that says that the mail is sent...
        #self.the_mail_feedback.text="" #will uncomment when it works to reset feedback
    except:
        self.the_mail_feedback.text="Failed To Send Mail... Check Credentials
```

Of course there are other ways to structure it, but the general idea is that instead of locking the event loop the function updates the label text then schedules some more tasks before handing control back to the eventloop. The eventloop then does its normal tasks including setting the graphical label to 'Sending...' like you want, before performing the scheduled function to finish sending.

You may also find it necessary or useful to look at sending the email from a separate thread, to avoid locking the ui, though it might be fast enough to be okay. You can do this quite easily, though you have to be careful to only perform graphics operations in the main thread.

Comment: thank you I shall try it tomorrow(extremely tired) and I am sure that is the answer because I was reading a bit about the main loop and it makes sense to me now.thank you again.